# Android Using Two Spinner Select click Submit button open new activity

Tags: android, spinner, dropdown

Android Studio, Using Two Spinner (dropdown box) Select click Submit button open new activity page.

Answer (score 0):

Give your Submit button an id.

```
android:id="@+id/submit" >>>In your xml file.
```

Create a variable before onCreate functions.  >>>>In your java file.

```
public class Acces_Database extends AppCompatActivity {

Button buttonSub;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_acces__database);

 buttonSub = (Button)findViewByid(R.id.submit);
 buttonSub.setOnClickListener(new View.setOnClickListsener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
   startActivity(new Intent(Your_CurrentActivity_name.this,Your_NextActiivty_name.class));
            }
        });
```

Hope i answered your question ,if any irrelevancy ,please let me know.

Happy Coding!